# Multi column and multi row table in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

How do I draw the following table in LaTeX? The data inside is not that important.

[image]

I wrote the following code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
    \hline
     \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Feature Vector of Samples} \\
     \hline
    \headerrow  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    1 & \(9.87*e^{-01}\) &  \(8.67*e^{-17} \)&  \(4.13*e^{-24}\) &  \(1.16*e^{-17}\) &  \(4.58*e^{-17}\) \\
    
    2 & \(1.16*e^{-16}\) &  \(9.99*e^{-01}\) &  \(9.14*e^{-25}\) &  \(3.63*e^{-22}\) &  \(2.69*e^{-11}\) \\
    3 & \(4.35*e^{-33}\) &  \(7.85*e^{-34}\) &  \(9.93*e^{-01}\) &  \(3.74*e^{-04}\) &  \(4.55*e^{-34}\) \\
    4 & \(5.51*e^{-26}\)&   \(5.13*e^{-31}\)&   \(5.02*e^{-04}\)    & \(9.99*e^{-01}\) &    \(1.71*e^{-29}\) \\
    5& \(9.60*e^{-18}\) & \(2.21*e^{-07}\)& \(2.52*e^{-25}\)&   \(4.64*e^{-20}\)&   \(9.99*e^{-01}\)
         
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{wasssss}
  \label{tbl:wasss}
\end{table}
```

and here is the result:

[image]

What I need to add is one multi row, and the first row should not include the first column.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that shows us how far you got yourself? I'm sure we can then help you do the rest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In theory you could create a table like this using the following code, but please have a look at http://betterposters.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-data-prison.html before you inflict such a table on your readers

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} &\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Feature Vector of Samples} \\
     \cline{3-7}
     \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\\hline
  \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{samples}}  & 1 & \(9.87*e^{-01}\) &  \(8.67*e^{-17} \)&  \(4.13*e^{-24}\) &  \(1.16*e^{-17}\) &  \(4.58*e^{-17}\) \\\cline{2-7}    
    &2 & \(1.16*e^{-16}\) &  \(9.99*e^{-01}\) &  \(9.14*e^{-25}\) &  \(3.63*e^{-22}\) &  \(2.69*e^{-11}\) \\\cline{2-7}
   & 3 & \(4.35*e^{-33}\) &  \(7.85*e^{-34}\) &  \(9.93*e^{-01}\) &  \(3.74*e^{-04}\) &  \(4.55*e^{-34}\) \\\cline{2-7}
   & 4 & \(5.51*e^{-26}\)&   \(5.13*e^{-31}\)&   \(5.02*e^{-04}\)    & \(9.99*e^{-01}\) &    \(1.71*e^{-29}\) \\ \cline{2-7}
   & 5& \(9.60*e^{-18}\) & \(2.21*e^{-07}\)& \(2.52*e^{-25}\)&   \(4.64*e^{-20}\)&   \(9.99*e^{-01}\)\\
   \hline  
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{wasssss}
  \label{tbl:wasss}
\end{table}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can use the excel2latex. It's a powerful tool for tables write. You'll need add the packagins after, like it's on the follow script:

https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow} %for multirow
\usepackage{rotating} %for sideways, rotating "samples" at 90°"
\usepackage{bigstrut} %for bigstrut

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Planilha1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{}} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Feature Vector of Samples} \bigstrut\\
\cline{3-7}    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{5}[10]{*}{\begin{sideways}samples\end{sideways}} & 1     & Value & Value & Value & Value & Value \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-7}          & 2     & Value & Value & Value & Value & Value \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-7}          & 3     & Value & Value & Value & Value & Value \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-7}          & 4     & Value & Value & Value & Value & Value \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-7}          & 5     & Value & Value & Value & Value & Value \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%


\end{document}
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: The `multicolumn` package is for setting documents with multiple columns per page, not for the `\multicolumn` macro used in tables

Comment: Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz.